# How to set a command to be hidden by default in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse plug-in that contributes a command to a toolbar. I got a request to make it hidden by default (but it should be possible to enable it in the **Customize Perspective** menu).

I have tried to use the `visibleWhen` attribute (by enabling it only with a non-existing perspective), the command is hidden by default, but in the **Customize Perspective** menu it is grayed out and it isn't possible to enable it.

Is there any way to have a command contribution to a toolbar disabled by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
   <perspectiveExtension
         targetID="*">
      <hiddenToolBarItem
            id="command_id">
      </hiddenToolBarItem>
   </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```